# Python: How do I retain NaTs when filtering df by a date time column to exclude dates older than a specific date?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a df with a date time column of expiration dates for employee certifications.  Some certifications never expire, however, and those are 'NaT' in the column.

I want to filter the df for dates after a certain date ('2019-12-31') while KEEPING NaTs as well.

Initially I tried:

```
valid_cert = tcert[tcert.cert_expire_dt>='2019-12-31']
```

which filtered out the NaTs.  I then tried adding

```
 or (tcert.cert_expire_dt == 'NaT')
```

before the final bracket (with parentheses around the previous condition as well), but that didn't work.

Comment: One way I thought of doing this is by converting NaT values into a date far in the future--say '3000-01-01'.  But I'd need to convert back later, and wonder if there's a better way?

Comment: There is an `.isnat()` function that returns true if the column is a NaT.  Maybe `tcert[tcert_expire_dt>'2019-12-31' | tcert.expire_dt.isnat()]`